How VersionedCollapsingMergeTree avoid concurrency issue?
The doc from Real-time Updates from Multiple Threads says

A VersionedCollapsingMergeTree table is quite handy when you want to implement deduplication while inserting rows from multiple clients and/or threads.

But it still need a cancel row to cancel previous row.
So if I have a existing table with id as pk having one row:
┌──id─┬─author──┬─views─┬─version─┐─sign─┐
│ 123 │ ricardo │   150 │    1    │   1  │
└─────┴─────────┴───────┴─────────┴──────┘

Two concurrent client could still concurrently add two different set of rows:
client1:
┌──id─┬─author──┬─views─┬─version─┐─sign─┐
│ 123 │ ricardo │   150 │    1    │  -1  │
│ 123 │ ricardo │   200 │    2    │   1  │
└─────┴─────────┴───────┴────────────────┘

client2:
┌──id─┬─author──┬─views─┬─version─┐─sign─┐
│ 123 │ ricardo │   150 │    1    │  -1  │
│ 123 │ ricardo │   250 │    2    │   1  │
└─────┴─────────┴───────┴────────────────┘

I believe that would lead to  logical error.
So how could VersionedCollapsingMergeTree handle concurrency better if it still need synchronization between clients?

It assumes you are able to specify the correct version in the seperate threads i.e. you have some concurrency control over the version external to clickhosue

@gingerwizard If I got that kind of control, CollapsingMergeTree is already enough. This design seems pretty conflicted.

It effectively allows the threads to operate out of order, which is distinct from the CollapsingMergeTree. This can help throughput in some scenarios and make scaling insert threads easier - less coordination. But you still need some notion of which version is more recent external to clickhouse. But you're right, it still requires a level of control which likely means often collapsing is sufficient.

@gingerwizard Thanks, I understand now, VersionedCollapsingMergeTree allow us to only use a global atomicLong while CollapsingMergeTree require us to use a lock.
